# Malfunctioning of Tab and Space Key in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008-sp1

When I write a code vs2008 editor , and give space it typed "....." and when I give tab it shows arrow symbol.

How to resolve this to make it function as it does have.

waiting for your prompt and positive response
Thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the View Whitespace option enabled.

To turn it off, go to the Edit menu, select Advanced and deselect View White Space.

Comment: +1.  I was puzzling over the question trying to figure out what he was seeing, but you nailed it.

Comment: Thanks.  I learned this the hard way - by trying to undo something I accidentially did!